# android MediaPlayer for video. problems starting

Tags: android

how do i reference a video and play it using mediaPlayer and VideoViewer, when the file is in my raw folder

iv tried

```
videoview.setVideoPath("android.raw://com.example.movievp8");
```

as well as

```
MediaPlayer video1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.movievp8);
```

once I have referenced it should i just hit video1.start();

also does anyone know where i could get like a full sample code on how to use media player for videos, just the basics.

Comment: This looks like an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861415/to-play-video-files-using-mediaplayer-class-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
MediaPlayer video1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.movievp8);
video1.start();
```

should works (but you will only have audio).

One way to do it is using a VideoView (where your video will be displayed) and a MediaController (to have some predefined buttons such as Play, pause, stop, etc.)

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
MediaController controller = new MediaController(vv.getContext());
vv.setMediaController(controller);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + videoID));
vv.start();
```

Remember that the simulator doesn't support video. You'll need to use a real device for testing video.